# Does Mailkit library for .NET automatically handle SMTP injection?

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit library (latest version) to send emails for my .NET project. However, I'm having a concern for SMTP injection handling. Does anyone happen to know some references that can confirm Mailkit supports SMTP injection prevention?

From a source I found https://snyk.io/blog/avoiding-smtp-injection/, most common email libraries like JavaMail, RubyMail, etc, already take care of that concern. Given that Mailkit is pretty popular too, I'm hoping it also supports that. Yet, I cannot find any trusted source or documentation specifically tells that Mailkit has the SMTP injection handled.

Comment: Have you tried tricking MailKit into doing any of the described injection scenarios? I'll try when I get a chance, but it would be hugely helpful if someone could run through the scenarios and tell me which ones MailKit is vulnerable to. Off the top of my head, I don't expect MailKit to be vulnerable to any of these because of the way MimeKit/MailKit deconstruct email address tokens internally and header strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only vulnerability that I was able to find was if the developer sets the `SmtpClient.LocalDomain` property to a user-supplied string (which could contain a newline sequence).

Under normal operation, developers should not set this value and should let MailKit auto-detect it.